# Can spotlight do Int > Hex conversion ?

Tags: spotlight

Spotlight is great to do some fast calculation and conversions.

But can he also do some geeky conversions like **Integers** <> **Hexadecimals** or **Integers** <> **Binary** ?

Comment: Don't think so, but calculator can, Cmd 1/Cmd 3 to swap between

Comment: @Tetsujin Man, I wish I could up vote your comment 100 times! For development with RGB <--> HEX, your little tip is a huge time saver! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I use Alfred for the Mac -- one of the most used tools I have. https://www.alfredapp.com

You will need the PowerPack for workflows. As a user I would recommend the lifetime update option. It keeps getting better and better.

There is an Alfred workflow created: https://github.com/obstschale/NSC/ that easily does number format conversion.

Answer (score 0):

This proposes a free alternative to the answer posted above:

As far as I know it can't.

But Alfred is an app that does most things Spotlight can do just as well or better: https://www.alfredapp.com.

If you set the default search engine in Alfred to DuckDuckGo you can use DuckDuckGo to convert hex to int and vice versa. It works quite nicely [0xF1 to int](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=0xF1&t=osx&ia=answer) and [241 to hex](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=241%20to%20hex&ia=answer).